# Wear OS app communicates with phone in debug only

Tags: android, wear-os, android-bluetooth, google-play-console, android-wear-data-api

I have a Wear OS and phone application that communicate with eachover fine when run through android studio on debug mode with the phone connected to the watch via bluetooth.

However, for testing purposes and distribution I have published the Wear OS application via the Google Play Console as an internal test and the phone app simply via sharing the .apk via google drive.

When I launch the internal test published Wear OS application and install the shared .apk from google drive the phone and watch do not communicate with eachover.

Is there something I am missing here? Is there perhaps an easier way to distribute the watch and phone app together to test?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to communicate the two applications must be signed with the same certificate. To be able to upload to the Play Store you must sign with a proper certificate. Make sure that you also sign the other application using the same certificate, and not just the default debug certificate.